# SQL Server 2008 R2 improving query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

**I have a query:**

```
SELECT  
      2015, 
      d.TransactionQuater, 
      atc1bf.atc1_id, 
      atc2bf.atc2_id, 
      atc3bf.atc3_id, 
      atc4bf.atc4_id, 
      bf.BU_id, 
      mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
      pbf.Product_id, 
      SUM(d.Units) AS Units, 
      SUM(d.ExMnf_LC*Units) AS ExMnf_LC
FROM dbo.FF_Data_2013_short AS d 
INNER JOIN ATC1ByFCC atc1bf ON d.FCC = atc1bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC2ByFCC atc2bf ON d.FCC = atc2bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC3ByFCC atc3bf ON d.FCC = atc3bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC4ByFCC atc4bf ON d.FCC = atc4bf.FCC
INNER JOIN ManufacturerByFCC mbf ON d.FCC = mbf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ProductByFCC pbf ON d.FCC = pbf.FCC
INNER JOIN BUByFCC bf ON d.FCC = bf.FCC 
WHERE d.TransactionQuater between  1 AND 1
GROUP BY 
       TransactionQuater,  
       atc1bf.atc1_id,
       atc2bf.atc2_id,
       atc3bf.atc3_id,
       atc4bf.atc4_id,
       bf.BU_id, 
       mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
       pbf.Product_id
```

This query executes about 13 minutes and fetches about 16000 records. If I comment group by and sums, query executes more faster and fetches about 4000000 records. I hope SQL Server can work better with group by. I think, I created all needed indexes. 
I have 2 another queries like that, and try to insert its results into #TempTable. This is to slow for me.
Could you help me this performance of this query?

**Added:**
I founded some improvements for the first query. Now it takes 7 seconds. But I have 2 another queries:

```
SELECT  
      2014, 
      d.TransactionQuater, 
      atc1bf.atc1_id, 
      atc2bf.atc2_id, 
      atc3bf.atc3_id, 
      atc4bf.atc4_id, 
      bf.BU_id, 
      mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
      pbf.Product_id, 
      SUM(d.Units) AS Units, 
      SUM(d.ExMnf_LC*Units) AS ExMnf_LC
FROM dbo.FF_Data_2014_short AS d 
INNER JOIN ATC1ByFCC atc1bf ON d.FCC = atc1bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC2ByFCC atc2bf ON d.FCC = atc2bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC3ByFCC atc3bf ON d.FCC = atc3bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC4ByFCC atc4bf ON d.FCC = atc4bf.FCC
INNER JOIN ManufacturerByFCC mbf ON d.FCC = mbf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ProductByFCC pbf ON d.FCC = pbf.FCC
INNER JOIN BUByFCC bf ON d.FCC = bf.FCC
GROUP BY 
       TransactionQuater,  
       atc1bf.atc1_id,
       atc2bf.atc2_id,
       atc3bf.atc3_id,
       atc4bf.atc4_id,
       bf.BU_id, 
       mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
       pbf.Product_id
```

It has no condition and takes about 8 minutes and gets about 65000 records
and

```
SELECT  
      2013, 
      d.TransactionQuater, 
      atc1bf.atc1_id, 
      atc2bf.atc2_id, 
      atc3bf.atc3_id, 
      atc4bf.atc4_id, 
      bf.BU_id, 
      mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
      pbf.Product_id, 
      SUM(d.Units) AS Units, 
      SUM(d.ExMnf_LC*Units) AS ExMnf_LC
FROM dbo.FF_Data_2013_short AS d 
INNER JOIN ATC1ByFCC atc1bf ON d.FCC = atc1bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC2ByFCC atc2bf ON d.FCC = atc2bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC3ByFCC atc3bf ON d.FCC = atc3bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC4ByFCC atc4bf ON d.FCC = atc4bf.FCC
INNER JOIN ManufacturerByFCC mbf ON d.FCC = mbf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ProductByFCC pbf ON d.FCC = pbf.FCC
INNER JOIN BUByFCC bf ON d.FCC = bf.FCC 
WHERE d.TransactionQuater between  2 AND 4
GROUP BY 
       TransactionQuater,  
       atc1bf.atc1_id,
       atc2bf.atc2_id,
       atc3bf.atc3_id,
       atc4bf.atc4_id,
       bf.BU_id, 
       mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
       pbf.Product_id
```

It takes about 4 minutes and gets about 45000 records

**I continue my experiments:** Following query:

```
SELECT  
      2011, 
      d.TransactionQuater, 
      atc1bf.atc1_id, 
      atc2bf.atc2_id, 
      atc3bf.atc3_id, 
      atc4bf.atc4_id, 
      bf.BU_id, 
      mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
      pbf.Product_id, 
      SUM(d.Units) AS Units, 
      SUM(d.ExMnf_LC*Units) AS ExMnf_LC
FROM dbo.FF_Data_2011_short AS d with(ForceScan)
INNER JOIN ATC1ByFCC atc1bf ON d.FCC = atc1bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC2ByFCC atc2bf ON d.FCC = atc2bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC3ByFCC atc3bf ON d.FCC = atc3bf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ATC4ByFCC atc4bf ON d.FCC = atc4bf.FCC
INNER JOIN ManufacturerByFCC mbf ON d.FCC = mbf.FCC 
INNER JOIN ProductByFCC pbf ON d.FCC = pbf.FCC
INNER JOIN BUByFCC bf ON d.FCC = bf.FCC 
WHERE d.TransactionQuater between  2 AND 4
GROUP BY 
       TransactionQuater,  
       atc1bf.atc1_id,
       atc2bf.atc2_id,
       atc3bf.atc3_id,
       atc4bf.atc4_id,
       bf.BU_id, 
       mbf.Manufacturer_id, 
       pbf.Product_id
```

executes 2 minutes with FORCESCAN and 4 minutes without FORCESCAN. Plans are here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B5ED432740B0672D!175&authkey=!AEM8f7O8qazZVK0&ithint=folder%2c
Data table has only 3 indexes:

1. FCC with include all another fields in table
2. TransactionQuater, FCC
3. TransactionQuater with include all another fields in table

I suppose what something wrong with indexes

Comment: In SSMS, include Actual execution plan by clicking the button or pressing `ctrl+m`, and run the query. This will add another tub in the results section called `execution plan`. If will give you the data needed to see where the bottle necks in your query are, and may even advise you to add indexes.

Comment: I tried to view execution plan. It has no useful information for me

Comment: The plans are: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B5ED432740B0672D!172&authkey=!ACBf1-8iSzdiXq0&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: They do seem ok, can't you apply the same solution you did for the first query to the other 2?

Comment: I have already done it. It reduce execution time, but it stil to large (as in question)

Answer (score 0):

The plan shows a cardinality estimation failure.

[image]

The green operators are estimated to execute 1 times but they are executed 100,000 times.

I have no time right now to find out why there is a cardinality estimation error. That would be the preferred approach. Maybe better statistics or indexes can help. The join right before the first marked operator is misestimated. Investigate that. Create better indexes on the joined columns.

A quick solution is to slap `FORCESCAN` onto those table references. This will likely cause SQL Server to pick a hash join and get you a stable plan. `FORCESCAN` is very non-invasive. Join hints unfortunately force join order which is unbearably stupid behavior on SQL Servers part. It makes join hints unusable in most situations even when they would be appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use this hint because error: "forcescan" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90. I don't understand, Is it bug?

Comment: Did you do it like in the example here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx Do you have the minimum required SQL Server version?

Comment: Do you need a new solution or can you apply SP1? It's a good idea anyway.

Comment: I tried to use FORCESCAN. Number of executions was reduced. But query executed slower

Comment: Post the new plan. The reason for the slowdown can be seen by the plan.